# How can I create persistent SSH connection to "stream" commands over a period of time?

Tags: linux, ssh

Say that I have an application running on one PC that is sending commands via SSH to another PC on the network (both machines running Linux).

For example every time something happens on #1, I want to run a task on #2. In this setup, I have to create SSH connection on every single command.

Is there any simple way to do this with basic unix tools without programming custom client/server application? Basically all I want is to establish a connection over SSH and then send one command after another.

Comment: [Independent *file descriptors* for one or more *SSH* connections.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553028/27653)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure if it can be used in production but you can do something like this:

create file on #1

1> `touch /tmp/commands`

Then run command:

1> `tail -f /tmp/commands | ssh username@x.x.x.x`

That will open file /tmp/commands and start sending its content to server x.x.x.x (#2) and run it there line by line

now, every time something happens on #1 do:

1> `echo "ls -l" >> /tmp/commands`

or

1> `echo "reboot" >> /tmp/commands`

whatever you add to file /tmp/commands will be sent to #2 and executed. Just make sure you do not run anything interactive, or deal with it somehow.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for, very creative solution :)

Comment: I'd add that you should use `tail -F`, which will detect that the file has been replaced, so when it gets to be giant you can erase it and start over with a new file.

Comment: @DerfK, alternatively, `mkfifo /tmp/commands` should be a better solution

Comment: @solotim full sample: [Independent *file descriptors* for one or more *SSH* connections.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553028/27653)

Answer (score 29):

**Automatic Persistency Using OpenSSH**

You can also use the `ControlMaster` feature of OpenSSH, which opens a unix domain socket for the first connection and reuses this connection in all subsequent calls.

To enable the feature, you can either use `-M` as the command line switch or enable the `ControlMaster` option in your `~/.ssh/ssh_config`, e.g.:

```
ControlMaster auto
```

Additionally, you should set the `ControlPath` using the following lines in your `~/.ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host *
   ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
```

To maintain a persistent connection to a host, e.g. if you want to run a script which needs to establish many ssh connections to the host, none of which persistent over the whole lifetime of the script, you can start a silent connection in advance using:

```
ssh -MNf remotehost
```

Cheerio,
nesono

Comment: I signed into server fault just to +1 vote your answer. Yours worked!

Comment: `ssh -N` starts a session without remote command, seems no corresponding options in ssh_config.

Comment: You may also want to configure `ControlPersist 480m` (adjust time to preference) to keep the connection alive for some time even after the SSH session has ended, to avoid having to re-enter your password/MFA each time.

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` add

```
# Send keep alive signal to remote sshd
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run into this sort of thing a lot, try [Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). It is like dsh (distributed shell) but has some neat features like counting semaphores and it is actively maintained.

From the documentation:

**EXAMPLE: GNU Parallel as queue system/batch manager**

GNU Parallel can work as a simple job queue system or batch manager. The idea is to put the jobs into a file and have GNU Parallel read from that continuously. As GNU Parallel will stop at end of file we use tail to continue reading:

```
echo >jobqueue; tail -f jobqueue | parallel
```

To submit your jobs to the queue:

```
echo my_command my_arg >> jobqueue
```

You can of course use -S to distribute the jobs to remote computers:

```
echo >jobqueue; tail -f jobqueue | parallel -S ..
```

There are many great examples that just scratch the surface. Here is a cool one.

**EXAMPLE: Distributing work to local and remote computers**

Convert *.mp3 to *.ogg running one process per CPU core on local computer and server2:

```
  parallel --trc {.}.ogg -j+0 -S server2,: \
  'mpg321 -w - {} | oggenc -q0 - -o {.}.ogg' ::: *.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible with a pipe:

```
echo 'echo "hi"' | ssh -i my_private_key tester@host2
```

this will execute the command echo "hi" on host2

you just have to write a programm, that just gives out the commands ( don't forget the ; ) and then pipe that output to ssh

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use program like dsh (Distributed SHell) that is made to do just that :), After configuring it with host names and setting up publickeya auth, you can use it to run commands on multiple machines either in series ("run on machine a then run on machine b") or in pararell ("run on all machines on same time").
Or just make script

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh machine -- $@
exec $@
```

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: I can't test this right now, as I'm on a windows machine with bash but without ssh.

In a bash script, you can do something like this:

```
exec 4> >(ssh --ssh-options-here user@host)
```

And then to send commands, write them to FD 4.

```
echo 'echo hi' >&4
```

If you do it this way, you can't access the results of the commands easily, but based on your question it doesn't seem like you need to.